# Visual C++: Unsuccessful communication through serial port with Arduino

Tags: c++, arduino

I am starting with Visual C++ and I am trying to write a program that sends and receives certain Data with an Arduino. However, it doesn't seem to work properly. For example, when using Compare::String even when I am sending the exact same word from the Arduino it returns 1 instead of 0.

The visual C++ code is as follows:

```
private: System::Void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(System::Object^  sender, System::ComponentModel::DoWorkEventArgs^  e) {
    while (true)
    {
        try {
            String^ tempVal = Arduino->ReadLine();
            this->SetText(tempVal); //Calls the secure method for analyse the incoming data
            Arduino->DiscardInBuffer();
        }
        catch (TimeoutException^) {
        }
    }
}
delegate void SetTextDelegate(String^ text);
private: String^ IDemitter;
private: String^ Subred;
private: String^ Data;
private: String^ Options;
private: int Memoria;
private: void SetText(String^ texto)
{

    if (this->textReceive->InvokeRequired)
    {
        SetTextDelegate^ d = gcnew SetTextDelegate(this, &MyForm::SetText);
        this->Invoke(d, gcnew array<Object^> { texto });
    }
    else
    {

        if (String::Compare(texto, "DATA") == 1) { //Theoretically it should be 0, but it returns 1
            this->Arduino->WriteLine("OK");
            this->textReceive->Text = "OK";
            Memoria = 1; 
            texto = "0";
        }
        else if ((Memoria == 1) && (String::Compare(texto, "0") != 0)) { //It never reaches this stage... 
            IDemitter = texto;
            this->Arduino->WriteLine("OKID");
            this->textReceive->Text = "OKID";
            Memoria = 2;
            texto = "0";
        }
        else if ((Memoria == 2) && (String::Compare(texto, "0") != 0)) {
            Subred = texto;
            this->Arduino->WriteLine("OKSUB");
            Memoria = 3;
            texto = "0";
        }
        else if ((Memoria == 3) && (String::Compare(texto, "0") != 0)) {
            Options = texto;
            this->textReceive->Text = "OKOPT";
            this->Arduino->WriteLine("OKOPT");
            Memoria = 4;
            texto = "0";
            if (Options != "9") {
                this->ProcessData(IDemitter, Subred, Options);
            }
        }
        else if ((Memoria == 4) && (String::Compare(texto, "0") != 0) && (Options=="9")) {
            Data = texto;
            this->Arduino->WriteLine("OKDATA");
            this->textReceive->Text = "OKDATA";
            Memoria = 5;
            texto = "0";
            this->ProcessData(IDemitter, Subred, Options, Data);
        }
    }
}
```

And the simplified Arduino code is as follows.

```
String confirmation;

void setup () {
Serial.begin(9600);
while(!Serial) { ; }
}

void loop () {

while(confirmation!="OK"){
Serial.println("DATA");
delay(5000);
confirmation=Serial.readString();
}
Serial.print("3"); //IDemitter
while(confirmation!="OKID"){
confirmation=Serial.readString();
}
Serial.print("2"); //Subred
while(confirmation!="OKSUB"){
confirmation=Serial.readString();
}
Serial.print("7"); // Options
while(confirmation!="OKOPT"){
confirmation=Serial.readString();
}
```

The idea is to operate in ProcessData() once I have received all the parameters, but it is being more difficult that I thought it should be. 
Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the `String::Compare(texto, "DATA")` call, and when you reach that line, take a really good look at the contents of `texto`.  Is there any whitespace?  Unexpected length mismatch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Append a newline to the "DATA" string sent from Arduino's program. Then, the readline from the PC should work properly.

Comment: Ok thanks! This seems to solve the problem with the Compare part. However, it gets stuck in the first else if when Memoria is equal to 1. The Arduino doesn't seem to receive correctly  that "OK". Any thoughts? I have tried to add \n sending "OK\n" but no response.

Comment: You need to empty the variable `texto` - as long as it remains "DATA\n", your first if is always true.